# Where contains throw Value can't be null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, ormlite-servicestack

I'm stuck and don't know why this issue occurs.

Normally we do like this:

```
var q = await OrmDb.SelectAsync<OrmProductSerial>(p => p.SerialNumber.Contains(reqSearch) );
```

In this case I need do like this, but it throws an error. Doesn't ormlite support this ? ( linq can do it )

```
var q = await OrmDb.SelectAsync<OrmProductSerial>(p => reqSearch.Contains(p.SerialNumber) );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/9f0b0e8cfa4410da5d288bf754ba6538805cbec0), for `ormlite`, you need to use `Sql.In` instead, something like this:

```
OrmDb.SelectAsync<OrmProductSerial>(p => p.Where(c => Sql.In(c.SerialNumber,reqSearch)));
```