# ServiceStack OrmLite "Like" Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, orm, servicestack

In my database I have field `string(max)` called `GROUPS` where i store groups for my record separated by semicolon `;`. I use `Service Stack ORM Lite` and `Linq` to get records that have selected group assigned to. Using `SQL` i can achieve this using `LIKE` query in example:

```
WHERE GROUPS LIKE 'selected_group' OR GROUPS LIKE '%;selected_group' OR GROUPS LIKE '%;selected_group;%' OR GROUPS LIKE 'selected_group;%'
```

I need to do the same in `C# Linq Query` but I have problem. I dont know how to create query for the edge examples. If I search group named **"cat"** using my expression :

```
q = q.Where(x => x.Groups.Contains($";cat;") || x.Groups.Contains($";cat")
       || x.Groups.Contains($"cat;") || x.Groups.Equals("cat"));
```

I will get records that have this group. But query also return records with group **"caterpillar"** if those records have 2 groups **"house;caterpillar"**. `SQL` Expression would exculde this kind of sittuation. Is there any clever solution to this problem directly in C# code ?

Comment: That WHERE's not valid SQL.

Comment: You are right i forgot about filed before like thank you. Edited already

Comment: You can use `Sql.In` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60108922/2946329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use `.EndsWith()` instead, e.g:

```
q.Where(x => x.Groups.EndsWith(";cat;"))
```

The OrmLite docs contains more [OrmLite Example queries](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#api-examples).